# My script works in jsFiddle but not in my webpage

Tags: html

I don't usually like asking other people to look at my code, but I'm so confused!  This script only works in jsFiddle.  When I try it elsewhere, it just comes up with the navy background.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" >
 <head>
 <meta name="google-site-verification" content="MaEIpDKrtwWJCsgK-26zGQY0-WFYBN8y2fDho0pzYcE" />
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >

 <style type="text/css">
 .scr { height:700px; width:400px; background-color:navy;}
 </style>

 </head><body>

 <div class="scr"><script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://geoff.lequelenec.googlepages.com/stock_chart_gadget.xml&amp;up_symbol=PPL&amp;up_duration=v&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=200&amp;title=PPL+Corporation&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script></div>

  </body></html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should give a link to the jsfiddle that works...

Comment: share the js fiddle link, before that make sure you have added a valid script file

Comment: Is it possible to do that and have it come up on the same page?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I tried all 3 of the 'share' links in jsFiddle and they only partially show up.  I thought it might be the link itself, but that doesn't explain why it works in jsfiddle.

Comment: Just copy-paste the URL here. Remember to click the save button first to save any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the [script link](http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://geoff.lequelenec.googlepages.com/stock_chart_gadget.xml&up_symbol=PPL&up_duration=v&synd=open&w=320&h=200&title=PPL+Corporation&border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&output=js) into a browser, it returns an error message:

```
Sorry! Gadget cannot be displayed until all required settings are provided.
```

So I would guess that you haven't fully configured it.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that! It must be the specific Google gadget I'm using because it's definitely fully configured. :/  Thanks for the advice!